# Making Oracle Regexp_Replace Non-Greedy?

Tags: regex, oracle

I'm confused about how to make the following non-greedy:

```
   Select Regexp_Replace('YAFTA Known Policy, insuring vendor and assigns,^^ in the amount of #ABC_HAFT_MORTGAGE_AMT#, ``ABC_HAFT_MORTGAGE_AMT^^ ^^ with #XYZ_SALES_FOO_TXT# approvals,``XYZ_SALES_FOO_TXT^^ ^^ lorem ipsum something something'
,'\^\^([[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]*?)``XYZ_SALES_FOO_TXT\^\^',
            'tttttttt')
from dual;
```

Result:

> YAFTA Known Policy, insuring vendor and assigns,tttttttt ^^ lorem
>   ipsum something something

Expected result:

```
YAFTA Known Policy, insuring vendor and assigns,^^ in the amount of #ABC_HAFT_MORTGAGE_AMT#, ``ABC_HAFT_MORTGAGE_AMT^^ tttttttt ^^ lorem ipsum something something
```

That is, the regex should have only matched:

```
 ^^ with #XYZ_SALES_FOO_TXT# approvals,``XYZ_SALES_FOO_TXT^^
```

But it doesn't. Can this be fixed somehow?

Comment: In your example, it works if you add a (space)`\s` as the first character in your regex. like so `\s\^\^([[:alnum:][:punct:][:space:]]*?)``XYZ_SALES_FOO_TXT\^\^` and replace with: `(space)tttttttt`. Example: http://regex101.com/r/dN5aJ0. Let me know if this works for you and is an adequate solution.

Comment: actually, there can't be a space there. Anyway, I learned that regex's go from left to right not right to left. A solution would be a way to instruct Oracle to switch to a right-to-left orientation for the command, but in the meantime, I just made do by moving the upper case identifier to the far left like: `\^\^XYZ_SALES_FOO_TXT``...rest of regex`